# using a if statement inside django model that is updating the model when threshold is reached

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-models

Please bear with me as I'm new with Django

I have in the model a table where I need to put a timer. If the timer limit is reached, we update the row of the column accordingly.

This is my model

```
class Question(models.Model):

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('date'
                                ))
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                  verbose_name=_('first name'),
                                  blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                 verbose_name=_('last name'),
                                 blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,
                              verbose_name=_('email address'),
                              blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('phone'),
                             blank=True)
    extra = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('extra'),
                             blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('subject'
                               ), blank=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1000,
                               verbose_name=_('question'))
    relevance = models.BooleanField(default=True,
                                    verbose_name=_('relevance'))
    marketing_consent = models.BooleanField(default=False,
            verbose_name=_('marketing consent'))

    expert = models.ForeignKey(Expert, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                               null=True, blank=True,
                               verbose_name=_('expert (target)'))
    analysis_tags = models.ManyToManyField(AnalysisTag, blank=True,
            verbose_name=_('analysis tags'))

    predicted_experts = models.ManyToManyField(Expert,
            through='AssociatedExpert', related_name='predicted_for',
            blank=True)
    public_token = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                    default=generate_token,
                                    db_index=True, unique=True,
                                    verbose_name=_('public token'))

    STATE_CHOICES = (
        ('W', 'Waiting'),
        ('D', 'Declined'),
        ('T', 'Taken'),
        ('A', 'Answered'),
        ('F', 'Feedback'),
        ('P', 'Pending'),
        ('C', 'Cancelled'),
        )
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATE_CHOICES,
                             default='P', verbose_name=_('state'))
```

What I want to do is to add the following but I'm unsure if the model is the right place to add the method below and also if I'm writing correctly that.

**Update** : I want a check in the background and mark the questions as `Cancelled` if the questions reach the time limit of 48 minutes

```
def value(self):
48_mn_ago = now() - timedelta(minutes=48)
if self.date > 48_mn_ago and self.state == 'P':
    return self.state = 'C', self.first_name = '***', self.last_name = '***'
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more than ok to have custom methods or properties operating with an instance in your model, they can be used as regular Python classes. But I am a bit unsure what you are trying to do in return. If you need to change the object (row), you should change its field and call self.save()

```
def update_if_rotten(self):
    48_mn_ago = now() - timedelta(minutes=48)
    if self.date > 48_mn_ago and self.state == 'P':
        self.state = 'C'
        self.first_name = '***'
        self.last_name = '***'
        self.save()
```

Usage:

```
question = Question.objects.create(...)
question.update_if_rotten()
```

Comment: Hi @cepbuch, please have a look at my update and thank you for your answer.

Comment: @andy-k, can you please explain: Do you want to perform this check during the creation process of an object (and modify it in some cases) - i.e. as a part of data validation. Or you want to check it every time the object is saved (any field is changed)? Or may be you want it to be checked constantly like in 'background'?

Comment: If it is the last one, I assume you can't do it fully automatically. You should either run a Django Command (for example every minute), that will check your questions. Or you should update availability in your view when list of questions is returned.. I have found the case similar to yours here: https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/asm09y/implementing_a_countdown_timer_in_django

Comment: I want a check in the background and mark the questions as `Cancelled` if the questions reach the time limit of 48 minutes. Does it make sense?